# Does #'adjoin in Common Lisp work as per HyperSpec when used with `:key`?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

Looking at the [docs for #'adjoin](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_adjoin.htm#adjoin) in the HyperSpec, I see the following in the Examples section:

```
(setq slist '()) =>  NIL
(setq slist (adjoin '(test-item 1) slist)) =>  ((TEST-ITEM 1))
(adjoin '(new-test-item 1) slist :key #'cadr) =>  ((TEST-ITEM 1))
```

I would have expected the following, instead:

```
(adjoin '(new-test-item 1) slist :key #'cadr) =>  ((NEW-TEST-ITEM 1) (TEST-ITEM 1))
```

My expectation is due to the following text in the [HyperSpec (17.2.1)](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm):

> When an object O is being considered iteratively against each element
>   Ei of a sequence S by an operator F listed in the next figure, it is
>   sometimes useful to control the way in which the presence of O is
>   tested in S is tested by F. This control is offered on the basis of a
>   function designated with either a :test or :test-not argument.

and, further:

> The object O might not be compared directly to Ei. If a :key argument
>   is provided, it is a designator for a function of one argument to be
>   called with each Ei as an argument, and yielding an object Zi to be
>   used for comparison. (If there is no :key argument, Zi is Ei.)
>
> The function designated by the :key argument is never called on O
>   itself. However, if the function operates on multiple sequences (e.g.,
>   as happens in set-difference), O will be the result of calling the
>   :key function on an element of the other sequence.

So we have slist (the sequence, S) as `'((TEST-ITEM 1))` and O as `'(new-test-item 1)`. To check if O should be adjoined, the function `#'cadr` is applied to the element(s) of S, the first being `'(test-item 1)`. So, that test gives:

```
(cadr '(test-item 1)) => 1
```

Now, when O, `'(new-test-item 1)`, is checked against the result of applying `#'cadr` to E1 of S with `#'eql` (the equality function used when none is supplied with `:test`), the `false` result should mean that O is adjoined. At least that's what I would think. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the HyperSpec and [Issue ADJOIN-SPECIFICATION](http://www.cliki.net/Issue%20ADJOIN-SPECIFICATION) has been written about it on the CLiki.  The relevant parts are:

> #### Problem Description:
>
> CLHS specifies ADJOIN behavior in presence of a :KEY argument by reference to Section 17.2.1 Satisfying a
>   Two-Argument Test. This is incorrect, since section 17.2.1 specifies
>   that the key function is NOT called on the ITEM parameter, but ADJOIN
>   does, as is specified in pushnew. Proposal (ADJOIN:CLARIFICATION):
>
> #### Replace:
>
> > The test, test-not, and key affect how it is determined whether item
> >     is the same as an element of list. For details, see Section 17.2.1
> >     (Satisfying a Two-Argument Test).
>
> by:
>
> > Whether or not item is already a member of the list is determined by
> >     comparisons using :test or :test-not. The first argument to the :test
> >     or :test-not function is the result returned by the :key function (if
> >     supplied), applied to the item; the second argument is an element of
> >     the list as returned by the :key function (if supplied). If :key is
> >     supplied, it is used to extract the part to be tested from both item
> >     and the list element.
>
> #### Rationale:
>
> Clarification of the specification of ADJOIN.
>
> #### Current practice:
>
> All implementations implement ADJOIN as specified on pushnew, and not as specified on adjoin.